# Derivative using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate $g(x) = (1-x)\left[\cos\left({\pi\over2}x\right){\pi\over2}\right]$

So (...)

$$g'(x)=-\left[\sin\left({\pi\over2}x\right){\pi\over2}\right]+\left[\cos\left({\pi\over2}x\right){\pi\over2}\right](1-x)$$

This is well done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question needs *both* the chain rule *and* the product rule. If you have two function multiplied together then $(fg)' = f'g+fg'$. Let $f(x) = 1-x$ and $g(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$. Obviously $f'(x)=-1$. To find $g'(x)$ we need the chain rule.

To differentiate $\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$, think of $\frac{\pi}{2}\cos u$. Differentiating gives $-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin u$. Then we multiply by the derivative of $u$, i.e. by the derivative of $\frac{\pi}{2}x$ which is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)\right)'=-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$

Putting all of this together gives:

$$\left((1-x)\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right)' = -\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right) -(1-x)\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$$

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez The LaTeX that you entered hasn't rendered. I think you might be missing a bracket, or might have too many curly brackets. One thing I can confirm is that $\left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$.

Comment: Sorry, again: This is equivalent to write $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)\right)'= {\frac{\pi}{2}}^2 {\left(-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right)}$ ?

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez Yes, absolutely! (You need brackets around the first factor of $\frac{\pi}{2}$)

Comment: Yes, sorry. And thank you very much, tomorrow I have an exam of mathematical analysis an dou saved me.

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez No problem. Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $\pi/2$ is a constant factor of the function, we need to apply the product rule and the chain rule:

$$g(x) = f(x)\cdot h(x) = \underbrace{(1-x)}_{f(x)}\cdot\underbrace{\left[\cos\left({\pi\over2}x\right){\pi\over2}\right]}_{h(x)}$$

$$g'(x) = f'(x)h(x) + f(x)h'(x)$$

$$g'(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \left[(1-x)\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right] = \underbrace{-}_{(f'(x)}\underbrace{\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)}_{h(x)}+\underbrace{(1-x)}_{f(x)} \underbrace{\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)}_{h'(x)}$$

$$g'(x)  = -\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{4}(1-x) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$$